# Aligning Radiobutton text in android

Tags: android, radio-button

In my application i am showing a radiobutton group. The button appearing on the left side of the text. I want the text to be on the left side of the button. Please note that i am using the an`android:text="My Text"` to specify the reason of the button.

Answer (score 0):

```
<TextView android:layout_width="20dp"
    android:layout_height="22dp"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
    android:textSize="20dp"
    android:text="text"/>
 <RadioButton
    android:id="@+id/rd0"
    android:layout_width="20dp"
    android:layout_height="20dp" />
```

You can also use textview to place radio button. But don't use `android:text="My Text"` for Radio Button

Comment: Yes i want to display the text on the left side

Comment: then is this answer help you?

Comment: how this is aligning in your layout?

Comment: RadioButton is on left side and follows the text

Comment: you need to display in reverse order?

Comment: Yes I want to display it in reverse order

Comment: i tested in my layout its displaying right. are you using linear layout and set orientation to the horizontal